# Unknown component apex:coloumn

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <h1>
        Edit Account
    </h1>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Accout">
            <apex:pagemessages/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Name}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Phone}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Industry}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{! Account.AnnualRevenue}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton  Action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.contacts}" var="contact">
                <apex:column>
            <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR ($Action.contact.Edit,contact.Id)}">
                Edit
                </apex:outputLink>
               &nbsp;
                <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR ($Action.contact.Delete,contact.Id)}">
                Del
                </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:coloumn value="{!contact.Name}"/>
                <apex:coloumn value="{!contact.Title}"/>
                <apex:coloumn value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

Change

```
<apex:coloumn value="{!contact.Name}"/>
```

To

```
<apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
```